# I want my div to move as my browser is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a website for a friend's birthday. I used parallax for a nice scrolling effect to outline her rings. However, the rings are only centered when I'm on full screen (15" screen). The rings don't move when I resize my page. I want the whole parallax div to keep centered and move when the browser is smaller. The images don't resize either they just disappear behind the browser. I know that if I'm not viewing the page on my screen size, the page looks off. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

https://upliftjewelry.org/rings.html

[This is how it shows when the browser is smaller in width, pictures cut off and nothing moves.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IGUg.jpg)

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

    const target =  document.querySelectorAll('.scroll')
    
    var index = 0, length = target.length;
    for (index; index < length; index++) {
        var pos =  window.pageYOffset * target[index].dataset.rate;

        target[index].style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, '+pos+'px, 0px)';
    }

});

/* Image 1 */

function hideAll() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#988780";
    document.getElementById("maintitle").style.color = "#e3e3de";
    var sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName("maintext");
    var index = 0;
    length = sidebar.length;
    for (index; index < length; index++) {
        sidebar[index].style.color = "#e3e3de";
    }
}

function showAll() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#e3e3de";
    document.getElementById("maintitle").style.color = "#265935";
    var sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName("maintext");
    var index = 0;
    length = sidebar.length;
    for (index; index < length; index++) {
        sidebar[index].style.color = "#2B4B42";
    }
}

function hide1(x) {
    document.getElementById("l_img_1").style.opacity = "0";
    hideAll();
}

function show1(x){
    document.getElementById("l_img_1").style.opacity = "1";
    showAll();
}

/* Image 2 */

function hide2(x) {
    document.getElementById("l_img_2").style.opacity = "0";
    hideAll();
}

function show2(x){
    document.getElementById("l_img_2").style.opacity = "1";
    showAll();
}

/* Image 3 */

function hide3(x) {
    document.getElementById("l_img_3").style.opacity = "0";
    hideAll();
}

function show3(x){
    document.getElementById("l_img_3").style.opacity = "1";
    showAll();
}

/* Image 4 */

function hide4(x) {
    document.getElementById("l_img_4").style.opacity = "0";
    hideAll();
}

function show4(x){
    document.getElementById("l_img_4").style.opacity = "1";
    showAll();
}

/* Image 5 */

function hide5(x) {
    document.getElementById("l_img_5").style.opacity = "0";
    hideAll();
}

function show5(x){
    document.getElementById("l_img_5").style.opacity = "1";
    showAll();
}

/* Image 6 */

function hide6(x) {
    document.getElementById("l_img_6").style.opacity = "0";
    hideAll();
}

function show6(x){
    document.getElementById("l_img_6").style.opacity = "1";
    showAll();
}

/* Image 7 */

function hide7(x) {
    document.getElementById("r_img_1").style.opacity = "0";
    hideAll();
}

function show7(x){
    document.getElementById("r_img_1").style.opacity = "1";
    showAll();
}

/* Image 8 */

function hide8(x) {
    document.getElementById("r_img_2").style.opacity = "0";
    hideAll();
}

function show8(x){
    document.getElementById("r_img_2").style.opacity = "1";
    showAll();
}

/* Image 9 */

function hide9(x) {
    document.getElementById("r_img_3").style.opacity = "0";
    hideAll();
}

function show9(x){
    document.getElementById("r_img_3").style.opacity = "1";
    showAll();
}

/* Image 10 */

function hide10(x) {
    document.getElementById("r_img_4").style.opacity = "0";
    hideAll();
}

function show10(x){
    document.getElementById("r_img_4").style.opacity = "1";
    showAll();
}
```

```css
@font-face { font-family: Bebas; src: url('/Fonts/Bebas_Neue/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf'); }
@font-face { font-family: cormorant; src: url('/Fonts/Cormorant/Cormorant-Medium.ttf'); }
@font-face { font-family: maharlika; src: url('/Fonts/Maharlika-Regular.ttf'); }
@font-face { font-family: poppins; src: url('/Fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Bold.ttf'); }
body {
    background-color: #e3e3de;
}

#maintitle {
    font-family: maharlika;
    color: #265935;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Only for non-index */

#main_title_container {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* end */

.maintext {
    font-family: cormorant;
    color: #2B4B42;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    text-orientation: sideways;
    padding: 20px;   
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 4.5rem;
    margin-top: 7rem;
}

.maintext:hover {
    color: #BF621E;
}

#homepage {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#instaLink {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#abtMel{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#ringpage {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#abrydabout {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#contactinfo {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* End of Base CSS */

.sidebar_right {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 7rem;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -7rem;
}

#orderInfo {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.parallax_effect {
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    margin-left: 5rem;
    margin-right: 5rem;
    width: 70rem;
    text-align:center
}

.parallax_effect_left {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    margin-left: 12rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    height: 160rem;

}

.parallax_effect_right {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    margin-right: 12rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    height: 160rem;
}

#l_img_1 {
    margin-bottom: 15rem;
}

#l_img_2 {
    margin-bottom: 15rem;
}

#l_img_3 {
    margin-bottom: 15rem;
}

#l_img_4 {
    margin-bottom: 15rem;
}

#l_img_5 {
    margin-bottom: 15rem;
}

#l_img_6 {
    margin-bottom: 15rem;
}

#r_img_1 {
    margin-top: 15rem;
    margin-bottom: 15rem;
}

#r_img_2 {
    margin-bottom: 15rem;
}

#r_img_3 {
    margin-bottom: 15rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/rings.css">
        <title>Uplift Jewelry</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main_title_container">
            <a id="homepage" href="index.html"><h1 id="maintitle">Uplift Jewelry</h1></a>
        </div>
        

        <div class="sidebar">
            <a id="ringpage" href="rings.html"><h3 class="maintext">Rings</h3></a>
            <a id="abtMel" href="about.html"><h3 class="maintext">About Melina</h3></a>
            <a id="abrydabout" href="abryd.html"><h3 class="maintext">Abryd Morocco</h3></a>
            <a id="instaLink" href="https://www.instagram.com/uplift.jewelry/" target="_blank"><h3 class="maintext">Instagram</h3></a>
            <a id="contactinfo" href="contact.html"><h3 class="maintext">Contact Info</h3></a>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar_right">
            <a id="orderInfo" href="orderInfo.html"><h3 class="maintext">Ordering Details</h3></a>
        </div>

        <!-- End of Base HTML -->

        <!-- Parallax -->

        <section>
            <div class="parallax_effect">
                <!-- Left -->

                <div class="parallax_effect_left">
                    <img class="scroll" onMouseOver="hide1(this)" onMouseOut="show1(this)" id="l_img_1" data-rate="-1.2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">               

                    <img class="scroll" onMouseOver="hide2(this)" onMouseOut="show2(this)" id="l_img_2" data-rate="-1.2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">

                    <img class="scroll" onMouseOver="hide3(this)" onMouseOut="show3(this)" id="l_img_3" data-rate="-1.2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">

                    <img class="scroll" onMouseOver="hide4(this)" onMouseOut="show4(this)" id="l_img_4" data-rate="-1.2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">

                    <img class="scroll" onMouseOver="hide5(this)" onMouseOut="show5(this)" id="l_img_5" data-rate="-1.2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">

                    <img class="scroll" onMouseOver="hide6(this)" onMouseOut="show6(this)" id="l_img_6" data-rate="-1.2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
                </div>

                <!-- Right -->

                <div class="parallax_effect_right">
                    <img class="scroll" onMouseOver="hide7(this)" onMouseOut="show7(this)" id="r_img_1" data-rate="-.3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">

                    <img class="scroll" onMouseOver="hide8(this)" onMouseOut="show8(this)" id="r_img_2" data-rate="-.3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">

                    <img class="scroll" onMouseOver="hide9(this)" onMouseOut="show9(this)" id="r_img_3" data-rate="-.3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">

                    <img class="scroll" onMouseOver="hide10(this)" onMouseOut="show10(this)" id="r_img_4" data-rate="-.3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- End of Parallax -->

        <script src="JS/rings.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your parallax_effect class change width to 100% instead of 70rem. and in scroll class add width:100% and height: auto.so you have:

```
.parallax_effect {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  margin-left: 5rem;
  margin-right: 5rem;
  width: 100%; /*change this line*/
  text-align: center;
}
/*add this*/
.scroll{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

also instead of all that image ids, target scroll class for margins. your code will be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the images sizes relative to the screen width.
Like  width:70%

Comment: The images get smaller but the parallax div still isn't centered. It still stays in the same place and gets cut off when the browser get's smaller. If someone view's the page on a smaller screen, the page looks off to them